# Prevent the delay time to fetch the data from firebase (Please check details for clarity)

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

Note:

1. The asynchronous nature of firebase has been discussed thousands of times here, but my low reputation number does not allow for a comment on an existing question. That's why I have asked this question.
2. I am a noob, so please help me understand the implementation in an easy to understand manner.

Steps to implement:

1. User enters a value in the HTML input box
2. Search the input value in the firebase db (showMessage() gets called)
3. Display an appropriate result based on the search result in step 2

Problem faced:
The message displayed in step 3 takes almost an average of 1.75 seconds to display. This experience is not user-friendly. I want to display the message as soon as possible i.e. want to reduce the fetch time.

Probable root causes:

1. Either my way of fetching the data from firebase dB is incorrect (I still don't understand how to keep a promise :()
2. Or The mechanism of search and display is not right

```js
var full_name; 

function showMessage(){
      extractData();
    }

function extractData(){ 
 test(function(returnValue) {
    custom_message = searchMessage(returnValue);
  var container = document.querySelector('#placeholder');
  var para = document.createElement('p');
  var custom_message = "Happy happy, buds!";
  para.innerHTML = custom_message;
  para.className = "message";
  container.appendChild(para);
 });
}

function test(callback) { 
 var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    callback(data); 
  }, function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error.code);
 });
}

function searchMessage(data){
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
     name_f_data = data[i].firstName.concat(" ", data[i].lastName);

  if(full_name.toLowerCase() == name_f_data.toLowerCase())
  {
   console.log(name_f_data.toLowerCase());
      console.log(full_name.toLowerCase());
   return data[i].message;
  }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell us how you invented a super fast no latency technology we're all ears.

Comment: Why don't you use firebase query API to get specific data which you want? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

Comment: @Darkrum [No sarcasm] I am not asking to do it instantly. I just feel the time taken is too high to be observed so evidently. Since I am a newbie, I want to confirm whether the current way is right and do I need to do something else to make it faster.

Comment: @HayTran Ok. Let me check. Do you mean to say that fetching the data via a query will reduce the overall time? 

Do you think that my current code implementation is a right way to take user data, search on the basis of it, and return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time a read operation takes depends on:

1. The latency of your connection to Firebase's servers
2. The amount of data you are reading
3. The bandwidth of your connection
4. The time it takes Firebase to process the request

In most cases, the time Firebase takes is only a very small portion of the total time, and most of your time actually goes to the data transfer, which depends purely on the bandwidth and amount of data. If this is the first time you're reading data from Firebase in the page, the latency also matters more, as Firebase has to establish a connection, which takes a few roundtrips.

Your current code is downloading all data from the database, and then searching in the JavaScript code for a child node that matches a certain value. The best way to reduce the time that takes (apart from upgrading to a fast connection) is to transfer less data, which you can do by using Firebase's query mechanism to do the filtering on the server.

You can get pretty close with:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();
var query = ref.orderByChild().startAt(firstName).endAt(firstName+"~");
query.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val();
  callback(data);
```

This will significantly reduce the amount of data transferred. A few notes though:

1. The query returns just the people that have the first name you're looking for. It does not yet filter on the last name, so you'll still need to filter that in the client-side code.
2. To further optimize this, store the full name (which you now compose in the client-side code) in the database so that you can query on that and reduce data transfer even more.
3. Firebase queries are case sensitive, so the query only returns data where the case matches exactly. If you want to query case-indifferent, consider storing a `toLowerCase()` value in the database.
4. Be sure to define an index on `firstName`, as otherwise the Firebase database will still send all data to the client, and the SDK will perform the filtering client-side.

Comment: Firstly, Thank you for taking out some time out of your schedule to reply to my basic question. It means a lot to me.

Second, I will write a query and make the suggested changes. Let me revert by evening.

Third, I didn't understand point 4. If I change the db field to full name rather than keeping first and last names, then do I still need to do what you're asking?

Comment: For #4, see the Firebase documentation on [database indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data). And yes, that is always needed to ensure Firebase performs the filtering on the server, which is the only way to remove the need for all data to be sent to the client.

Comment: When I used "ref.orderByChild('fullName').equalTo(fNameLower).on('value', gotData, errorData);", I am getting an array (of size 2) that also contains __proto__
How can I get just the matching records?

E.g.
1: {firstName: "olivia", fullName: "olivia parker", lastName: "parker", message: "Teacher"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: `proto` is just part of how your JavaScript console shows an object. If you want to see the actual JSON, do `console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));`